# How can I get a list of all file names having same prefix on Amazon S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am using `boto` and `Python` to store and retrieve files to and from `Amazon S3`.
I need to get the list of files present in a `directory`. I know there is no concept of directories in S3  so I am phrasing my question like `how can I get a list of all file names having same prefix?`

For example- Let's say I have following files-

```
Brad/files/pdf/abc.pdf
Brad/files/pdf/abc2.pdf
Brad/files/pdf/abc3.pdf
Brad/files/pdf/abc4.pdf
mybucket/files/pdf/new/
mybucket/files/pdf/new/abc.pdf
mybucket/files/pdf/2011/
```

When I call `foo("Brad")`, it should return a list like this-

```
files/pdf/abc.pdf
files/pdf/abc2.pdf
files/pdf/abc3.pdf
files/pdf/abc4.pdf
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use startswith and list comprehension for this purpose as below:

```
paths=['Brad/files/pdf/abc.pdf','Brad/files/pdf/abc2.pdf','Brad/files/pdf/abc3.pdf','Brad/files/pdf/abc4.pdf','mybucket/files/pdf/new/','mybucket/files/pdf/new/abc.pdf','mybucket/files/pdf/2011/']
def foo(m):
   return [p for p in paths if p.startswith(m+'/')]

print foo('Brad')
```

output:

```
['Brad/files/pdf/abc.pdf', 'Brad/files/pdf/abc2.pdf', 'Brad/files/pdf/abc3.pdf', 'Brad/files/pdf/abc4.pdf']
```

Using split and [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
 def foo(m):
    return filter(lambda x: x.split('/')[0]== m, paths)
```

Comment: That works.
Further, which method of the above would you advise to use if list `paths` is too big?

Answer (score 2):

user3's approach is a pure client side solution. I think it works well in small scale. If you have millions of object in one bucket, you may pay for many requests and bandwidth fee.

Alternatively, you can use delimiter and prefix parameter provided by GET BUCKET API to archive your requirement. There are many example in the document, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

Needless to say, you can use boto to achieve this.